# ShinydashboardPlus: "Error in validateBoxProps(title = title, label = label, sidebar = sidebar, : is.numeric(width) is not TRUE"

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinydashboardplus

```
Error in validateBoxProps(title = title, label = label, sidebar = sidebar,  :is.numeric(width) is not TRUE
```

Has anyone seen this code while trying to run a Shiny app? It appeared when  I started using library(shinydashboardPlus) and specifically the dropdownBlock command. I cannot find the trigger and the error sometimes disappears if I force kill R and rerun but has made my app very unstable.

Comment: without code, it's hard to say how this error got generated. looks like something is not right with `:is.numeric(width) is not TRUE`, what happens if you remove that code from your code?

Comment: I understand, unfortunately I cannot share anything from the source code. There is no validateBoxProps nor an is.numeric test in the code. And what is mostly surprising is that i cannot seem to find anything on Google regarding that which is nearly impossible.

Answer (score 1):

I get the same error since a couple of days. For reasons I do not understand, setting the `width` option of a box to `"100%"` doesn't work anymore. If you defined the width of a box in your code, try setting it to (a fraction of) 12. From the help:

> The width of the box, using the Bootstrap grid system. This is used
> for row-based layouts. The overall width of a region is 12, so the
> default valueBox width of 4 occupies 1/3 of that width. For
> column-based layouts, use NULL for the width; the width is set by the
> column that contains the box.

Comment: This fixed the error for me. Specifically I has some `tabBox(width = "100%")` in my code which I changed to `width=12`

Answer (score 1):

Use shinydashboard::box that seems to fix the issue